# Who is the woman who sings the ending song for "In the Beginning: The Bible Stories."

Tags: theme-song, in-the-beginning-the-bible-stories

I would like to know the name of the woman who sings the ending song for "In the Beginning: The Bible Stories." It is very hard to find detailed information about this show.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the information either in the Japanese Wikipedia [article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%89%8B%E5%A1%9A%E6%B2%BB%E8%99%AB%E3%81%AE%E6%97%A7%E7%B4%84%E8%81%96%E6%9B%B8%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E#%E4%B8%BB%E9%A1%8C%E6%AD%8C) for *In the Beginning: The Bible Stories* or the corresponding [aniDB entry](https://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=3184) under the Songs tab.

The ending theme is *Rainbow Blue* sang by [Reimy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reimy).